# Book about a water planet (not earth) with people living off slow moving air bubbles

Tags: novel, story-identification

It was about an all water world, where people were living under water.

They'd manage by catching air bubbles that would float slowly under water by catching them in contraptions they'd wear on their head.

If I remember correctly, the planet was created by some sort of portal from Earth, to dispose of extra seawater.

The people that live on this planet couldn't surface because it's too close to (a) sun, so they would die if they did.

A thing I also remember is the core of the planet was this 'being' that had mind controlling abilities.

Comment: This seems really familiar to me - as I recall the spheres were maintaining the sea level on earth by siphoning off excess water, and all the inhabitants had been inadvertently sucked through. I've a feeling that the 'being' you mention was jelly-like, and took control by entering the body - the hero of the story has a modern diving suit and is able to defeat the creature because it can't get past his mask.

Comment: Also, I probably would have read this in the early to mid '90s, but it would have come from a library, so who knows how old it was then.

Comment: Yes, that's it! The being would suck up other beings that came too close and they would become part of it (like a collective thoughts being, a swarm - not sure how to explain this in proper English, sorry). I can't remember the hero or how it ended though. I'm guessing it's over 20 years old, not 100% sure again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bingo! [Medusa's Children by Bob Shaw](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Medusas-Children-Bob-Shaw/dp/0575040963) seems to fit the bill.

The [Google Books](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Medusa_s_Children.html?id=GgxeGYSPRS8C&redir_esc=y) synopsis covers the basics.

Comment: That was my thought too just from the title. The water is at a Lagrange point.